# Why do I get an error trying to connect to a Win2k8 MSMQ queue from Windows 7?

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, windows-server-2008, msmq

I have a .NET3.5 application that connects to a remote queue (a private queue, running on Windows Server 2008).  The client recently was forced to upgrade the machine on which this application ran to Windows 7 from Windows XP.  Now, when my application attempts to connect to the remote queue it crashes with an error that it cannot connect to the remote queue.  Here is the exception message and the first couple lines of the stack trace:

System.Messaging.MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ResolveFormatNameFromQueuePath(String queuePath, Boolean throwException)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.get_FormatName()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.GetMessageEnumerator2()
   at

The remote queue's permissions are satisfactory ("Everyone" has "Full Control"), and I am running this application as Administrator.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Matthew Belk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a non-issue.  Had nothing to do with Win7 or anything like that.  Brainfart on my part.